# Selecting a row only if the calculated count is greater than 0

Tags: sql

I've seen similar questions about counts and limits on stackoverflow, but I haven't quite been able to apply it here. I'm calculating the count of other rows meeting certain conditions and displaying that count. But if the final count that is going to display is 0, I don't want it to show up at all.

Here's what I tried, using HAVING:

```
select p.[ref] as [ID],
p.[first] as [First],

(select count(distinct f.[id]) from [field] f 
where (f.[related] = p.[id]) and (f.[field] = 'person_that_called') 
having count(distinct f.[id])>0) as [Total Calls Made]

from [person] p
```

But this results in something like this displaying:

```
ID     First   Total Calls Made
--- |  ----  | ----------------
011 |  Bob   |       4
012 |  Susan |       2
013 |  Joe   |      Null
```

Without the HAVING section, Joe's "Total Calls" show up as 0. But how can I get Joe to not show up at all?

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag.  The syntax looks more like SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `join`:

```
select p.[ref] as [ID], p.[first] as [First], f.[Total Calls Made]
from [person] p join
     (select f.[related], count(distinct f.[id]) as [Total Calls Made]
      from [field] f 
      where f.[field] = 'person_that_called'
      group by f.[related]
     ) f
     on f.related = p.id
where [Total Calls Made] > 0;
```